# Data execution prevention and RWE regions

Tags: security, memory, memory-management, ollydbg

I looked at the memory map of an executable using Ollydbg, and noticed a region with access RWE. I thought that it is impossible to have both the W and E flags, for security reasons.

So:

1. Is it possible to have a region which is both writable and executable?
2. If yes - what about data execution prevention? what about XOR (eXecute Or wRite)?

Answer (score 1):

All self modifying executables need write and execute permissions
how do you think you can decrypt some bytes replace the original with another set of decrypted bytes  and execute the modified instructions

(thus every packer writes to section implying write access and executes the modified instructions so execute access

it is either done while compiling or done dynamically with VirtualProtect() function

Data Execution Prevention means it will not execute sections that are defined as data section 
dep does not prevent section being Declared as data and executable

Dep etc is used to mitigate execution in common areas like ProcessHeaps  not in image sections